# How to use PIP when it is not in your path on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am not the administrator of a computer I am using (where I just installed PIP [for windows 7]) therefore I can not add PIP to the `PATH`.

How can I run a command such as `PIP Install` from the command line when PIP is not in my `PATH`?

Comment: anyone can add stuff to their own personal %path%. you just can't do it for all users. and anyone can completely modify/replace %path% in a cmd shell anyways, but only for that one cmd session.

Comment: Just put the full path to pip e.g. `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe` so to install python-dateutil use `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install python-dateutil`

Comment: @MarcB are you saying that I should just make a new user variable called `%path%`?

Comment: no, you already have %path%. I'm saying that as a user you can put anything you want into your own personal %path% that the system builds for you. it's in the control panels -> system -> advanced settings or something.

Comment: I am not administrator so I am unable to access that variable.

Comment: Can't you just specify the full path?

Comment: @LennartRegebro that's the way. I had never done that before. Thanks